# Scroll to element inside scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble scrolling to element inside scrollable div.

My code is quite simple and it mimics exact problem I'm having in my bigger project. When I click on text on the left side it should scroll to element with the same `id` on the right side but its not working. It always scrolls to different position and I dont know why.

If you manage to help me can you also provide short explanation what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to jQuery. Thanks

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ber63qnz/3/)

```
$('.left span').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var element = $('.right span[id="' + id + '"]');
    $('.right').animate({ scrollTop: element.offset().top }, 500);
});
```

Comment: dont give same id to element first fix that.

Comment: This should be an example which simulate my problem. In my project I have more clever way how to target these elements. Fixing the same ids doesnt change anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok... So you had a few issues with your original code.

First don't duplicate ID's, it is bad practice and it is invalid.

The next issue you were having is that you were getting the offset top of your spans. [Offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) will:

> Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the
>   coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, **relative
>   to the document.**

Emphasis on "relative to the document."

What you need is position. [Position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) will:

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, **relative to the offset parent**.

Emphasis on "relative to the offset parent."

Now, the main issue was that you were getting the offset after the click. Which sort of worked for your first click, but after that all of the values for offset top were skewed by the new scroll position.

To fix this you need to loop through the elements and get their position before you start clicking.

Try something like this:

```js
$('.js_scrollTo').each(function () { // for each span
    var target = $(this).text(); // get the text of the span
    var scrollPos = $('#' + target).position().top; // use the text of the span to create an ID and get the top position of that element
    $(this).click(function () { // when you click each span 
        $('.right').animate({ // animate your right div
            scrollTop: scrollPos // to the position of the target 
        }, 400); 
    });
});
```

```css
.left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.right {
    position: relative; /* you'll need some position here for jQuery's position to work, otherwise it will be based on the document */
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    float: right;
    display: block;
}
.right span {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
    <div class="js_scrollTo">test1</div>
    <div class="js_scrollTo">test2</div>
    <div class="js_scrollTo">test3</div>
</div>
<div class="right">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameContrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame<span id="test1">test1</span>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameContrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame<span id="test2">test2</span> 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameContrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame<span id="test3">test3</span>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameContrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsumRenaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameContrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame<span id="test3">assasdasdasd</span>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameContrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem</div>
```

Comment: I couldnt hope for a better answer! I learned a lot. Thank you for actually reading what I was asking for and trying to understand my problem before answering. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should try like this:

```
document.getElementById("YOUR ID").scrollIntoView({
   behavior: "smooth",
   block: "start",
   inline: "start"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you should not give the same id twice on a page. 
give each span in the right for instance:

```
<span id="1to"></span>
```

and call the animate function for the element with *# + id + to*

```
var element = $('#'+id+'to');
$('.right').animate({ scrollTop: element.offset().top }, 500);
```

also you could position your .left "menu" at a fixed position and animate the whole html, body to the certain position.

try this fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/xchqw7uz/

works as you intend it to. 
and is easier to use, since you dont need so many ids

Comment: I did and it works just the same as it did before. http://jsfiddle.net/ber63qnz/8/

Comment: Please dont modify the rules. I could make it work when I try to animate whole html. I need it to work inside div.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble scrolling to element inside scrollable div (or other scrollable element) witch may be inside other scrollable element witch may be inside scrollable page or other scrollable element and so on.

I have spent some time and made the following decision:

```
utils.scrollVerticallyToElement(jqElement, true);
```

where **jqElement** is an element (wrapped in jQuery object) to scroll to, the second argument is a flag that indicates whether to animate scrolling process (**true** to animate) and **scrollVerticallyToElement** is a method of the following object:

```
var utils = {
    clearAllSelections: function() {
        //clearing selected text if any
        if (document.selection && document.selection.empty) {
            document.selection.empty();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
        }
    },

    getWindowClientVisibleRect: function () {
        var html = document.documentElement;
        var body = document.body;
        var doc = (html && html.clientWidth) ? html : body;

        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
        var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || html.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;

        var clientTop = html.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
        var clientLeft = html.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

        var windowLeft = scrollLeft - clientLeft;
        var windowRight = doc.clientWidth + windowLeft;
        var windowTop = scrollTop - clientTop;
        var windowBottom = doc.clientHeight + windowTop;

        return { left: windowLeft, top: windowTop, right: windowRight, bottom: windowBottom };
    },

    getScrollableElementVisibleRect: function (element) {
        var left = element.scrollLeft - element.clientLeft;
        var top = element.scrollTop - element.clientTop;

        return { left: left, top: top, right: element.clientWidth + left, bottom: element.clientHeight + top };
    },

    getCoordinates: function (element) {
        var top = 0, left = 0;

        if (element.getBoundingClientRect) {
            var windowRect = this.getWindowClientVisibleRect();
            var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

            top = Math.round(elementRect.top + windowRect.top);
            left = Math.round(elementRect.left + windowRect.left);
        }
        else {
            while (element) {
                top = top + parseInt(element.offsetTop);
                left = left + parseInt(element.offsetLeft);
                element = element.offsetParent;
            }
        }
        return { top: top, left: left, right: left + element.offsetHeight, bottom: top + element.offsetHeight };
    },

    scrollWindowVerticallyToElement: function (element) {
        var elemCoord = this.getCoordinates(element);
        var wndRect = this.getWindowClientVisibleRect();

        if (elemCoord.top < wndRect.top) {
            window.scrollTo(wndRect.left, elemCoord.top);
        }
        else if (elemCoord.bottom > wndRect.bottom) {
            window.scrollBy(0, elemCoord.bottom - wndRect.bottom);
        }
    },

    scrollVerticallyToElement: function (jqElement, useAnimation) {
        if (!jqElement || !jqElement.parent) {
            return;
        }

        var scrollToElement;
        if (!useAnimation) {
            scrollToElement = function(jq, scrollValue) {
                jq.scrollTop(scrollValue);
            };
        }
        else {
            scrollToElement = function (jq, scrollValue) {
                jq.animate({
                    scrollTop: scrollValue
                }, 'fast');
            };
        }

        jqElement.parents().each(function () {
            var jqThis = $(this);

            var top = Math.round(jqElement.position().top);
            var bottom = top + jqElement.innerHeight();

            var parentTop = Math.round(jqThis.position().top);
            var parentBottom = parentTop + jqThis.innerHeight();

            if (top < parentTop && jqThis.scrollTop() > 0) {
                scrollToElement(jqThis, jqThis.scrollTop() - parentTop + top);
            } else if (bottom > parentBottom) {
                scrollToElement(jqThis, jqThis.scrollTop() - parentBottom + bottom);
            }
        });

        this.scrollWindowVerticallyToElement(jqElement.get(0));
    }
};
```

This code was tested in Opera, Firefox and IE. And it really works!

*Please, fill free to use **utils** object in your project if you need (you may even rename it if you need).*